# How to extract array from Supabase with vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, supabase

I am trying to use certain parts of a array supabase send me.

I want to show naam with "gezonheid"in my app. This is the code i use.

```
 const quizdata = ref();
  async function getcontent() {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.from("quiz-content").select();
    quizdata.value = data;
    console.log("content", { data, error });
    
  }
```

if i then use {{quizdata }}

it shows
[ { "id": 1, "created_at": "2023-03-09T15:40:09.072973+00:00", "naam": "gezondheid", "tijd": 2 } ]

What i dont understand is. If i use a normal ref with some objects and then use for example data.naam is works correctly. But when using the array from firebase it wont work.

{{quizdata.naam}}  it doesnt work. Why is that?
i get a QuizView.vue:15 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'naam' error.

The entire code is use

```
<template>
  <main class="flex-1">
    <div class="py-16">
      <div class="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 sm:px-6 md:px-18">
        <h1 class="text-2xl font-semibold text-gray-900">Quiz</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 sm:px-6 md:px-8">
        <!-- Replace with your content -->
        {{ $route.params.id }}
        
        <div class="py-4">
          <div class="h-96 rounded-lg border-4 border-dashed border-gray-200" />
        </div>
        {{ quizdata }}
        {{ quizdata.naam }}
        <!-- /End replace -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>
<script setup>
  import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";
  import { supabase } from "@/libary/supabaseClient";

  const quizdata = ref();
  async function getcontent() {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.from("quiz-content").select();
    quizdata.value = data;
    console.log("content", { data, error });
  }

  onMounted(() => {
    getcontent();
  });
</script>
<style scoped></style>
```

I added .maybeSingle(); to the fetch now it seems to work. So i think the issue was that the objects are wrapped in a array. I am still curious how i can "unwrap"the array so that i only keep the object.

Comment: It's Supabase or Firebase?

Comment: It is supabase. thank for help

Comment: Until you load the data from Supabase you have to hide the `{{quizdata.naam}}`, because the value is empty. Also, `quizdata` is an array, so you cannot just access `naam` directly. You have to loop though each element and access the `naam` property of each one.